# How to use string function within CAST/CONVERT in t-sql (Azure Synapse)

Tags: t-sql, casting, type-conversion, azure-synapse

I have a table in Azure Synapse as below,

[image]

want to query the Enrolled_period column into 2 different column as DATE datatype.

I am trying following query

```
  select convert(varchar, SUBSTRING(enrolled_period, 2, 12), 23) as startdate
from dbo.test_period;
```

also trying to split the data

```
select 
REPLACE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(enrolled_period, ', ', '.'), 2), '(', '') AS startdate, 
REPLACE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(enrolled_period, ', ', '.'), 1), ')', '') AS enddate 
from dbo.test_period
```

But getting error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What data type is `enrolled_period`?  Also, note that date literals have `'` around them to denote that they're strings *(in need of conversion to dates)*, the strings themselves should not contain `'` characters.  So, you want 10 characters starting from character 3, not 12 characters starting from character 2.  Then you want to CAST/COVERT to a date, not to a VARCHAR.

Comment: We are migrating data from teradata to Synapse. Teradata(bteq) have datatype called period. That is was the enrolled_period column is.

But in Synapse(t-sql) does not support period datatype. So storing it as string

Comment: Much better to store it as two date columns.  Retreating to storing data as string representations is always fraught with issues; avoid it whenever you can.

Answer (score 2):

I created a test table and tried this, its working:

Please check :

```
select 
cast ( SUBSTRING(p,3,10) as date) , cast ( SUBSTRING(p,16,10) as date),p
from test2
```

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to cast/convert to a date it's prudent to test what the resulting substring looks like.

For example :

```
declare @enrolled_period varchar(30);
set @enrolled_period = '(''2021-10-11'', ''2021-10-31'')';

select @enrolled_period as enrolled_period
, substring(@enrolled_period, 3, 10) as start1
, substring(@enrolled_period, 17, 10) as end1
, RIGHT(PARSENAME(REPLACE(@enrolled_period, ''', ''', '.'), 2), 10) as start2
, LEFT(PARSENAME(REPLACE(@enrolled_period,  ''', ''', '.'), 1), 10) as end2

select @enrolled_period as enrolled_period
, CAST(SUBSTRING(@enrolled_period, 3, 10) AS DATE) as startdate
, CAST(SUBSTRING(@enrolled_period, 17, 10) AS DATE) as enddate
```

The 3th param for substring is a length, not a position.

*Extra*

Just to showcase that using STRING_SPLIT or JSON for this is possible, but would be overkill.

> ```
> declare @T table (
>   id int identity(1,1) primary key,
>   enrolled_period varchar(30)
> );
>
> insert into @T (enrolled_period) values
> ('(''2021-10-11'', ''2021-10-31'')')
> ;
>
> SELECT t.*, ep.startDate, ep.endDate
> FROM @T t
> OUTER APPLY (
>    select 
>     min(try_cast(substring(value,3,10) as date)) as startDate, 
>     max(try_cast(substring(value,3,10) as date)) as endDate
>    from string_split(t.enrolled_period,',') s
> ) ep;
>
>
> SELECT t.*, ep.*
> FROM @T t
> OUTER APPLY (
>   select v.js as period
>   , try_cast(json_value(v.js,'$[0]') as date) as startDate
>   , try_cast(json_value(v.js,'$[1]') as date) as endDate
>   from (
>     select replace(replace(replace(t.enrolled_period,'''','"'),'(','['),')',']') as js
>   ) v
> ) ep;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | enrolled_period              | startDate  | endDate   
> -: | :--------------------------- | :--------- | :---------
>  1 | ('2021-10-11', '2021-10-31') | 2021-10-11 | 2021-10-31
>
> id | enrolled_period              | period                       | startDate  | endDate   
> -: | :--------------------------- | :--------------------------- | :--------- | :---------
>  1 | ('2021-10-11', '2021-10-31') | ["2021-10-11", "2021-10-31"] | 2021-10-11 | 2021-10-31
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=caddd99eed60507139da8f29bee0aff7)*

Comment: My bad!!! I was considering even the quotes in substring, hence error. Thanks!!!

if we do select cast('2019-02-01' as date) as startdate, this works. Keeping this as reference considered quotes also

Comment: How can we use string_split function instead of parsename ??

Comment: @Kavyashree I've added a little extra.  But it's just to cumbersome for this.  Because we can be sure of the format in that field, since it comes from a teradata type as I understood.  The golfcoder in me favors the substring way.

Comment: SELECT Enrolled_period, 
case when ordinal=1 then cast(replace(replace(value, '(''', ''), '''', '') as DATETIME2) end as startdate,
case when ordinal=2 then cast(replace(replace(value, ''')', ''), '''', '') as DATETIME2) end as enddate   
FROM dbo.test_period  
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Enrolled_period, ',', 1)
order by Enrolled_period;


I put string_split() in this way. This looks easier. Let me know your thoughts

Comment: That it's cool to use the enable_ordinal flag of the string_split function. But directly cross applying to string_split is rather daring.  I still think the simple substring method is best.

Comment: ok!!! was wondering can we create a UDF for the same substring query and return those separated values?

Comment: Sure, but not me. But I think a UDF can only return 1 value or a table. So it would probably be accepting 2 params, the period string and a flag for start/end date return.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.person_Id,
       d.University_Name,
       CAST(LEFT(d.Enrolled_period, CHARINDEX (',', d.Enrolled_period) - 1) AS DATE) AS Start_Date,
       CAST(RIGHT(d.Enrolled_period, CHARINDEX (',', d.Enrolled_period) - 1) AS DATE) AS End_Date
FROM
       (
           SELECT d.person_Id,
                  d.University_Name,
                  (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (d.Enrolled_period, '(', ''), ')', ''), '''', '')) AS Enrolled_period
           FROM
                  (
                      SELECT 24569 AS person_Id,
                             'Gothenburg university' AS University_Name,
                             '(''2007-08-09'',''2009-08-25'')' AS Enrolled_period
                      UNION
                      SELECT 24568 AS person_Id,
                             'Gothenburg university' AS University_Name,
                             '(''2019-07-09'',''2021-06-25'')' AS Enrolled_period
                  ) AS d
       ) AS d
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

you need to remove "-"

```
select D.[start_date]
    ,D.[end_date]
from dbo.test_period T
    outer apply
    (
        select 
            replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
                T.enrolled_period
                ,'(', '')
                ,')', '')
                ,'''', '')
                ,',', '')
                ,'-', '')
                ,' ', '') as clean_period
    ) C
    outer apply
    (
        select
            cast(left(C.clean_period, 8) as date) as [start_date]
            ,cast(right(C.clean_period, 8) as date) as [end_date]
    ) D
```

Comment: Actually, ISO 8601 Date Literals include the hyphens...  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: @MatBailie, you are right. but there is one problem with hyphens. it's not applicable for date since ydm isn't supported for date. try this: set dateformat ydm; select cast('2018-08-25' as datetime). -- so it's not a good practice.